# In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?

Tags: c++, fstream

If I open a text file using fstream is there a simple way to jump to a specific line, such as line 8?

Comment: Yes, if all the lines are exactly the same length.

Comment: Yes, read 7 lines.  No, you can't jump if the lines are not a fixed length in bytes.

Answer (score 45):

Loop your way there.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}
```

Sets the seek pointer of `file` to the beginning of line `num`.

Testing a file with the following content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Test program:

```
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    fstream file("bla.txt");

    GotoLine(file, 8);

    string line8;
    file >> line8;

    cout << line8;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `8`

Comment: Is it the only way? We have to loop through every line (i.e. search for '\n', go there, search for the next and so on) just to move the pointer to a specific line? Isn't there a quicker solution?

Answer (score 7):

If every line has the same length then you can use istream::[seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/)() to jump to the location and read from there.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working and neat example with `std::getline()` if the lines have the same length:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const int LINE = 4;

int main() {
std::ifstream f("FILE.txt");
std::string s;

for (int i = 1; i <= LINE; i++)
        std::getline(f, s);

std::cout << s;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You probably don't need to leave `LENGTH` there. 2. `getline(src, str)` is a bit too wasteful here, I think.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post. I presented an alternative method using `getline`. It might not be the most performant one.

Comment: Actually, I meant that `LENGTH` wasn't a constraint. Your code up there *doesn't* need to know the length of lines (no need to 'have the same length'). Probably not a good idea to add that now, though ^^'

Comment: Yep, got it from the first time. I deleted the length, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, *no*, you have to walk down using a strategy similar to what [Xeo shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file/5207600#5207600).

If as [netrom says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file/5207587#5207587) you know the lines have fixed length, *yes*.

And even if the line lengths are not known in advance, but (1) you're going to want to jump around a lot and (2) you can guaranteed that no one is messing with your file in the mean time you could make one pass to form a index, and use that thereafter.

Comment: ... Why are you linking to the same question? "[you know the lines have fixed length, yes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5207550/365102)"

Comment: Do we really need these extraneous links to answers in this same question? They're not helpful at all.

Comment: @muntoo: It has been my habit since the beta to link to earlier answers on a question when repeating expanding on them.  I'll admit the formulation of the second one is sloppy and unclear.

Comment: The problem is that one expects a link on SO to reference a relevant but different question/answer. Your answer is a summary aggregator with a sentence of original content that would be better as a comment on netrom's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use while loop as well

```
fstream f;
f.open("bla.txt", ios_base::in);

int i = 1;
int line = 8;

while(i != line){
    f.ignore(1000, '\n');
    ++i;
}
string fContent;
f >> fContent;
cout << fContent;
```

> Note: create the file first

Comment: I'd recommend to use `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead of `1000`.