# How to - Read specific set of lines from a text file

Tags: c++, file, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Whats the smarter way to read specific set of lines (line number A to line number B) from a text file in C++ using standard C++ library (without opting to Boost)?

Comment: Instead of reading the file from start to match those line numbers for extracting text..!

Comment: I assume its manually counting the lines as you process line by line, consuming only the lines from A to B

Comment: @Vignesh: there is no smarter way. Unless there is some more information you didn't tell us, all you can do is guess where the lines A and B start.

Comment: If the lines aren't fixed length and you don't have some kind of index you can't do better than reading the whole file from the start and counting `\n`s

Comment: @awoodland Yep. The lines are not of fixed length.

Comment: @awoodland, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Martinho , Thanks. The file input.dat has whole data. And the file linenumbers.txt has selected line numbers in the format A\nB\nA\nB\nA\nB\n I wish to extract A to B from input.dat for additional processing. Do further information could help ?

Comment: @Vignesh: no that doesn't help :( The only thing that could help would be if the lines have a fixed-length, like awoodland said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the line length isn't fixed and you don't have an index you can't do better than counting the `\n`s.

Consider this example file:

```
Hello\nThis is a multi\n-line\nfile, where is this?\n\nAgain?
```

Line 1 starts at byte 0, Line 2 at 6, Line 3 at 22, Line 4 at 28, Line 5 at 49 and Line 6 at 50 - there's no pattern.

If we knew that information in advance, e.g. at the beginning of the file we had that information in some table we could compute a byte offset into the file for the lines we cared about and use a seek to jump straight there.

If the line width is fixed at 20 bytes:

```
Hello               \nThis is a multi     \n-line               \nfile, where is this?\n                    \nAgain?
```

Then we can compute the start of a line as a simple multiplication - an offset into the file.

---

If you're looking for a "generic" way of doing this I'd suggest something like:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <typename Iter, typename Count, typename T>
Iter find_nth(Iter it, const Iter end, Count c, const T match) {
  while(c > 0 && it != end) {
    if (match == *it++)
      --c;
  }
  return it;
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("test.txt");
  std::ostringstream str;
  str << in.rdbuf();

  const std::string& s = str.str();
  const int A=2, B=4;
  const std::string::const_iterator begin=find_nth(s.begin(),s.end(), A, '\n');
  const std::string::const_iterator end  =find_nth(begin,s.end(), B-A, '\n');

  const std::string range(begin,end);
  std::cout << range << std::endl;
}
```

This is appropriate for small-ish files (it reads the entire file into a `std::string`). For larger files you might want do do the same, but with `mmap` instead, using the mapped region as iterators. Or you could do this with a `RandomAccess` iterator that uses `seek()` within the file. (`std::istream_iterator` does not do this, it's only a `ForwardIterator` so wouldn't be appropriate).

Comment: @Vignesh - I updated it with an example of a generic way of reading from between lines A and B.

Comment: I got the idea and really nice and now I have to try with map (for larger files). Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well a way I think is to count the lines and to utput the line you want, I think better solution would be tags but well this is how I got it working, sorry for my noobieness:

In this example we want to read the line number 3 containing "Leo 3", oh and dont forget to include the libraries or headers: `iostream` `string` `fstream`:

```
int count;

string lines;
ofstream FileC("file.txt",ios::app);


lines = "Leo \nLeo2 \nLeo3 \n";
FileC << lines;
FileC.close();

ifstream FileR("file.txt");

for(count = 1; count <= 3; count++)
getline(FileR, lines);

cout << lines << endl;
```

Also if u want to make and if statement make sure it has an space after the word I thinks because of the way getline works:

```
if(lines == "Leo3 ")
{
    cout << "Yay!";
}
```