# C++: How to read from specific line in .dat file

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, I am trying to construct an array of pointers to type Students by reading through a .dat file where each line is of this form:

```
101 Jones 92.7 54.3 88 .4*88+.3*(92.7+54.3)
```

Each line will be an instance of struct and stored into an array of pointers to Students.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int N = 100;
struct Students{
        int classid;
        string lastname;
        float exam1;
        float exam2;
        float final;
        float score;
};


int main(void){
        Students* s[N];
        ifstream input;
        ofstream output; 
        input.open("examscores.dat");
        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
                s[i] = new Students; 
                input >> s[i]->classid >> s[i]->lastname >> s[i]->exam1 >> s[i]->exam2 >> s[i]->final >> s[i]->score;
        }
        cout << s[0]->classid << endl;
        cout << s[4]->classid << endl;
        cout << s[5]->classid << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I expect this output:

```
101
105
106
```

but I get:

```
101
0
0
```

Comment: Did you try expanding your `input >>` extraction to a list of singular extractions, tehn *using a debugger* to determine which one *failed* (and thus why the rest of also DOA) ? I'm fairly confident the first line is failing one fo the extractions, and after that the rest of the stream is dead until you clear the fail-bit. This really should be done with `std::getline()` and a `std::istringstream` line processor regardless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: ".dat" file is meaningless. Is it a *text* file?

Comment: @Rapptz OP doesn't want to go to a specific line in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.4*88+.3*(92.7+54.3)` does not fit in a `float`. You must read it as a string a parse the expression yourself.

When you use `input >> ... >> s[i]->score` it reads the `.4` but leaves the rest (`*88+.3*(92.7+54.3)`) in the buffer and screws up subsequent reads.

**Quickfix:** replace `float score;` by `std::string score;`