# Advanced File and String Operations

Tags: c++, string, file, directx, fstream

So I am working on a model loader in my DirectX 11 program, and I ran into what I think is a unique issue. So I spent a bit of time looking for a solution to this, but failed to do so. My problem is that in my file that has the texture path and list of vertices, I want to be able to pick out certain parts, and remove some aswell. Below my example file for a texture-less triangle:

```
T:0$
(0, 5, 0)
(5, 0, 0)
(-5, 0, 0)
```

^ THIS IS OLD, LOOK AT EDIT BELOW ^

Let me explain what's happening here. First, the "T:___" is my file path to the texture. I have set this to "0" because I am not using a texture. The "$" after the "T:0" is my program's mark for the end of the file path and beginning of the vertices.

Now, here is what I need my program to do.

**1.** Read the file until the character "$" has been reached. Then erase the first two characters(the "T:") and the "$" if it has been added as well. Finally put the remaining text into a string called TextureData. P.S. Don't erase the "T:" from the file, just my string(The file needs to stay untouched).

**2.** Put the remaining text(vertices) into a temporary string called VertexData, then maybe remove the parenthesis..? I would like to know how to do this, but maybe not use it at the moment.

I hope I made myself and my issue clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

--- IMPORTANT EDIT ---

I have changed my format a little bit, I looked at a .obj file and decided that that would be easier to do. My texture and vertex file now looks like this:

```
T:0$
v 0 5 0
v 5 0 0
v -5 0 0
```

--- END OF EDIT ---

This code here is what I have as a basis:

Model loading function:

```
bool LoadTVF(string FP)
{
    ifstream TVFReader;
    TVFReader.open(FP);
    if (TVFReader.is_open())
    {
        ReadLine(1);    // Function not fully working, need to improve
        // Load vertices and texture into strings
        TVFReader.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ReadLine function(made just to organize my code and jump to a certain line and retrieve that lines data and put into a string, the cutting and modifying of the string needs to be back in the main function):

```
string ReadLine(int character)
{
    return lineData;    // I know this doesn't work, just don't know what to return?
}
```

Honestly with this ReadLine function, I have no idea what I'm doing. I was just making some kind of frame to show you how I would prefer the code to be organized.

Once again, thank you.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I'll add that into the question, one second.

Comment: also, while you're at it: what are your questions?

Comment: I hope that's enough code. All I'm asking is just how to do this? I am kind of new to fstream, and I need help with this.

Comment: Note that parsing text files is a convenient way to learn the basics, but you shouldn't have production code doing all that parsing of text files that never change once you ship. Instead, games typically 'cook' the content into some binary format that is optimized for the platform and is simple or trivial to read. Some example options include CMO, VBO, or SDKMESH all of which are supported by [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) Model loader. Details on those formats are [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981) with links to tools like ``meshconvert``.

Comment: I was just making a simple excuse for a vertex and texture loader, I would not be using this in a commercial case. That is why I came up with stuff like my own file type, this is just a small learning experience for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
bool LoadTVF(string FP)
{
    ifstream TVFReader;
    TVFReader.open(FP);
    if (TVFReader.is_open()) {
        stringstream buffer;
        buffer << TVFReader.rdbuf();
        string texture_string = buffer.str();
        texture_string = texture_string.substr(2, texture_string.length());
        // Removes T:
        texture_string.erase(texture_string.begin() + texture_string.find("$"));
        // Removes the first occurrence of $
        std::cout << texture_string;
        /* This will print out:
         * 0
         * v 0 5 0
         * v 5 0 0
         * v -5 0 0
         */
        TVFReader.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't use a `ReadLine` function because it loads the entire string at once. Since I'm only manipulating that string at the beginning, I would rather have the parsing and pruning logic happen in one place.

If you must iterate line-by-line, there's already a way to do that using `getline`:

```
bool LoadTVF(string FP)
{
    ifstream TVFReader;
    TVFReader.open(FP);
    if (TVFReader.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while(getline(TVFReader, line))
        {
            // Do stuff with each line
        }
        TVFReader.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that these `line`s don't have end-of-line characters in them.

Edit:
As per OP's comments, here's how you would split up the parsed file into separate strings:

```
bool LoadTVF(string FP)
{
    ifstream TVFReader;
    TVFReader.open(FP);
    if (TVFReader.is_open()) {
        string header;
        getline(TVFReader, header);
        header = header.substr(2, header.length());
        // Removes T:
        header.erase(header.begin() + header.find("$"));
        // Removes the first occurrence of $
        std::cout << header << std::endl;
        // This should print 0, which is the string between T: and $

        stringstream buffer;
        string line;
        while (getline(TVFReader, line))
        {
            line = line.substr(2, line.length());
            // Removes the starting "v "
            buffer << line << std::endl;
            // We need the end-of-line here because its been stripped
        }
        string texture_string = buffer.str();
        std::cout << texture_string;
        /* This will print out:
         * 0 5 0
         * 5 0 0
         * -5 0 0
         */
        TVFReader.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A few notes I'd like to make here. If you're in control of the way your file is structured, you shouldn't need the `$` character to indicate the end of that line. The fact that there's a newline should be indication enough of that. Additionally, since every line after that represents a vector in a matrix, I don't think the `v` is necessary either. Finally, the `T:` may also be unnecessary if your files are named appropriately, like `"test.texture"`. That way you know that the file you're reading is a texture.

This would reduce the complexity of parsing these files, and as a bonus, reduces the storage sizes for these as well.

Comment: This looks great! But before I mark this as the Right Answer, I have two small problems. The first is `stringstream  buffer;` is giving me this error: _incomplete type is not allow_ Is there a missed parameter? And the second problem is I want to be able to isolate the "0" after "T:". All that is needed there is to erase everything after that.  Just a side note, it would be awesome if you could point me in the right direction to isolate the vertices by just removing the "v"s and the "T:0$" at the top! Thanks for your help!

Comment: For your first issue, include the header `<sstream>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, really glad you helped me out on this one. But, I must ask you why you don't think I need the "v" after each line? I think that I need this because how else am I going to define a new xyz vertex? If I didn't use this, wouldn't my ending string end up like this?: `0 5 05 0 0-5 0 0` And one more thing, people say that it is not possible for `getline` to pick out individual lines, unless all the lines have the same exact amount of characters. Is this true?

Comment: If each `x y z` vertex lives on its own line, then each line represents a new vertex. If you don't have the `v ` before each vertex, after parsing out the header, you can just do a `buffer << TVFReader.rdbuf()`, and get the string with `string texture_string = buffer.str()`. I suggest you try this out yourself and see what you get!

Comment: Yeah in general you can't just read a specific line from a file, you'd have to walk through the file somehow, i.e., you have to *read* the file to know when a new line begins, and using that you can count up to the line you want. I'm sure you've seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file) considering the way you asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

So far it looks like you can read your file line by line using [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then extract necessary information: figure out "line type" by checking first character, then depending on type either get substring with path or split line into chunks and convert them to floats.

Later when/if your file format becomes more complicated you might want to write a full blown parser probably using some sort of parser generator.