# Removing an entry inside a file using C++

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling

I have created a txt file using fstream command in CPP in this file I insert names of students but if I want to delete information of a PARTICULAR STUDENT AND NOT THE WHOLE FILE is it possible and how to do it.. thanks in advance... I don't want to jump to a line but I want to delete a specific line

Comment: Duplicate. Your answer is in one of the posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file

Comment: At some point you should buckle down and use a proper database. Even [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) is better than making your own hacked-together monstrosity.

Comment: @FirstStep my question and the link you shared are different the link shows going to a specific line and I want to delete a line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some methods:

1. Write all the "good" records to a new file, omit the deleted stuff.
2. Mark (overwrite) the text with '\0' to indicate a deleted record.
3. Open the file as read/write and move all the text after the deleted
   text so it overwrites the deleted text (think of moving items in an
   array).

Files don't automatically shrink when text or data is deleted; they stay the same size (treat them as arrays).

Comment: I would add a boolean `deleted` field.

Comment: @ZDF: Depends on the data format.  Usually, a Boolean field is not the best solution in a comma separated or new line terminated text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Read all record from file one by one

2. if (read_record==record_to be deleted)

         skip 

3. else

       write record into new temporary file

4. Repeat step from 2 to 3 till all file is read

5. now delete original file

6. rename temporary file to original name
```