# Issues with writing to a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

As part of parsing a file, my task involves stripping off all the comments in the file and then parsing the file. Once the parsing is completed, I need to insert the comments back at the same lines.

To strip of comments, I read the file and check if a comment has occured and then enter a newline there.  I use Ragel to do this, and the logic works fine.

```
example: file.cpp 

  #1 /** comments */
  #2 /** comments */
  #3 
  #4 ABCD : XYZ, 123
  #5 EFGH : ABC, 987

intermediate_file.cpp
 #1 
 #2 
 #3 
 #4 ABCD : XYZ, 123
 #5 EFGH : ABC, 987
```

The comments are stored with the line numbers in a `std::map<int,string>` , which is used later to iterate and output the string to the file, `intermediate_file.cpp`. I am using the below code for the same:

```
fstream m_fstr; //class member
std::map<int,std::string> m_Comments_map; //to hold the comments

void WriteBackCommentsToFile(void) {
  m_fstr.open("intermediate_file.cpp", ios_base::out);
  int LineNbr = 0;
  for(std::map<int,std::string>::iterator it = m_Comments_map.begin(); it != m_Comments_map.end(); ++it)    {
      LineNbr = it->first;
      if(m_fstr.is_open()) {
        m_fstr.seekg(std::ios::beg);
        GotoLine(m_fstr,LineNbr );
        m_fstr << it->second << endl;
      }
  }
}

std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        //getline(m_fstr,ReadLine); -- another try
    }
    return file;
}
```

After the parsing is complete, I am trying to write back the comments from the `m_Comments_map` to the file `intermediate_file.cpp`
With the above logic, I am able to print only the first line in the file - `/** comments */` .  The rest of the contents are not written back to the file.

I have tried printing out the contents of the `std::map` to console and verified that the comments are stored properly in the `std::map`.  The problem lies in printing out the `std::map` contents to the file. Can anyone tell me which part of my code is incorrect.?

I have implemented the above using the logic described here : 
[In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please! `GotoLine()` might only work for lines of same length. I'd recommend yo read all the lines into a `std::vector<std::string>`, do your changes and write back the vector completely to the file.

Comment: I know this is not the diy c++ solution, but use a regexp (e.g. sed 's!/\*\* *.* \*/!!g' YOURFILE) to get to the intermediate step.

Comment: @schorsch312 : I use Ragel to parse, and the parsing logic is fine. The comments are stored properly as well in the `std::map` . The only issue is with writing the comments back to the file.

Comment: Let's say you have a file 100 bytes long. You seek to byte 50 and write 10 bytes. The file is not 110 bytes long now, it's still 100 and you've overwritten whatever was already there.  Consider a solution where you look up the comment for the line as you write it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja : I get your point and now I know where I am going wrong! Ofcourse, I knew I could write to another new file, but I was trying to work out a solution so that I can write it to the same file  `intermediate_file.cpp`  may be writing to a new file is the better solution