# how to assign a letter to a specific number in a data in c++

Tags: c++

I new to coding in c++ & ROOT (CERN). I have this data below i.e.bounded by carriage return. I want to get only 1001.612999 as a number and assign it to a variable 'z'.

> ```
> # Space_ValveOpen_mca1.CNF [CR]
> #Real Live [CR] 1001.612999 999.999999[CR]
> 0      0
> 1      0
> ```

I used the code below but got nothing. Please can someone please assist me?

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("Space_ValveClosed_mca1.dat");
int z;
myfile >> z;
cout << z << endl;  

myfile.close();
```

Comment: You should read two lines with std::getline and apply std::regex "Real\sLive\s\[CR\]\s(\d+\.\d+)" to second line to extract target string. You should convert string to double precision number afterwards.

Comment: Just adding you may use `std::stod` to convert the number to a double, after extracting the substring containing the number with a regex.

Comment: @Minor Threat    Thank you for the fast response. I am new to c++, I barely could understand how I can incorporate std::regex "Real\sLive\s[CR]\s(\d+\.\d+)" to my code. Moreso, could you kindly show me how to convert string to double precision number after using std::regex

Answer (score 0):

I never advise reading user input via raw operator `>>`. Regarding your struggle with `std::regex`, I've decided to give you a code snippet. Don't ask what regex is, though.

PS: I've realized that [CR] is a carriage return symbol. This might simplify the regex to just `(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)`, but you have to apply it to the third line.

PPS: If you're trying to read your source data like you do in languages like R, your question looks much less stupid than I initially thought. C++ is a general purpose language, and therefore it lacks built-in routines for reading files in certain formats like CSV. The operator `>>` of an input stream isn't a table reading routine. It can't deduce that lines starting with `#` are comments. Worse, it breaks input stream because it can't parse `#` into integer nor report an error (C++ iostream library has been written when C++ was immature and therefore it has rather bizarre interface). So, it sets error flag on the input stream and otherwise does nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string source = "#Real Live [CR] 1001.612999 999.999999";
  std::regex extractNumbers(R"(#Real\sLive\s\[CR\]\s(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d*)?))");
  std::smatch matches;
  double num1, num2;

  if (std::regex_search(source, matches, extractNumbers)) {
    {
      std::istringstream is(matches[1].str());
      is >> num1;
    }
    {
      std::istringstream is(matches[2].str());
      is >> num2;
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "Match not found\n";
  }
  std::cout << num1 << ' ' << num2 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

[You can check this code online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eec1d8f0287b54d1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. I ran the code but see what I got

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness.See what I got         /Users/moses75/Desktop/Macro.C:21:12: error: no member named 'regex' in namespace 'std'
                    std::regex extractNumbers(R"(#Real\sLive\s\[CR\]\s(\... 
To solve this problem, I upgraded the boost,gtk+,gtk3+ and gcc. However, I cannot still resolve it. Please help me out

Comment: Have you tried to google std::regex? It could have revealed this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex. On this page, you could find that std::regex is located in #include <regex>

Comment: Yes I visited the site I added #include <regex> but got same result. I tried  #include <boost/regex> and #include <class.h> but it did not work.

Comment: If I want to repeat the same process on another data with the same length, I get the wrong number. I tried using the ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file  but I get the wrong answer. Is there a conventional of writing 'std::string source' that will work for any data that has same length? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please see what I did below     #include <iostream>
#include <regex>

#define FILE_NAME "phi-10.6_mca1.CNF.dat"
std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
  
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

int carriageextractor(){

    //FILE* pFile =fopen(FILE_NAME,"rb");
  fstream file(FILE_NAME);
  double num1, num2;
  
     GotoLine(file, 2);

      string line2;
   file >> line2;
  std::regex extractNumbers(R"(#Real\sLive\........

Comment: You can enter your code at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com like I did. Then, you can press the button 'Share' below and get the link.