# How to read a certain line from a file and read from that point below, in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I have a txt file, with some numbers. Let's say I have these lines.

124

559

774

12

145

698

So there are 6 lines, let's say, I would like to read the file from 12 and below, is there a function in c++ that returns the cursor of the file? I don't know prior what are the values, I was just trying to explain what I would like to do. 
So for example if I would like to read the values 12, 145, 698, is it possible, and ignoring the prior values, not deleting.

Comment: With text files, where each line could be of different length, you can't use file position (which you *can* get) as it depends in the previous contents and the length of the previous lines. If you want to process data from a specific line in the file you have to read all lines and check them for the starting point. The lines you read you can just discard.

Comment: so even if it's "myfile.txt" with only numbers on the file, I can't use the file position function?

Comment: Only, and ***only*** if the lines are all the *exact* same size. If you have even one line with a different number of characters then it's not possible.

Comment: For example, I have the number, 2, 34, 295, if, in some way, I don't know how, I add some special characters to: 2 and 34, so I can control the number of characters, then, might it be doable?

Comment: Oh and even if the lines are all the exact same length, you might still have to worry about line endings. The "newline" at the end of a line depends on the operating system the file was created on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file, I had found this, isn't more and less the same thing? the function does give back the cursor, no?

Comment: So, in the example given in the post, if I would like to read the values 12, 145 and 698, i should know the number of the amount of items read, and i have to know how many item have to scroll from down to up, to reach the reading point. Now my idea doable, or even that is not something possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use getline : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/
And call it in a loop to skip the first N lines.

Comment: i have read about it, and it says that the things written in the first amount of N lines that i would like to ignore, then are deleted, but that's not what i would like. I just would like to ignore them.