# Reading a specific row in CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, csv, visual-c++

I am writing a C++ code that would read a specific row on a CSV file, I succeeded to read the entire file with the code below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("test.csv");

    while (myFile.good()) {
        string line;
        getline(myFile, line, ',');
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

The code will give me every value in the csv file, but I would like to have the value of just one specific row in the file. I did some research, but not sure how to really do it.

Let's say that in my CSV file there are :

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

My current code would give me

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

as the result, but\I want just one specific row like 67890 as the result.

Comment: Read and discard the first `n-1` rows, then read and process the `n`th row. There's no other way.

Comment: Do you know what `std::getline` does, and how to use it?

Comment: Notice your input file does not have any commas in it.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern: `while (myFile.good()) {` a better loop would be: `while(std::getline(myFile, line)) {`

Comment: I did a quick research about the getline() function, but not sure how it works in the case of reading a csv file. I changed my while loop to while(getline(myFile, line)), and it gives me a better result, with two line of output that are 12345 and 67890, I think I will have to do some conditional statement inside the while loop to make the code just to show a specific line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("test.csv");
    string line;
    int n = 2;//desired row number
    int a = 0;//counter


    while (getline(myFile, line)) {
        a++;
        if (a == n) {
            cout << line << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

just figured out thanks to Martin York's comments, so that I can output the code row by row. By adding condition, the code will show only one line of the data in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use seek method to seek the file pointer to correct line then read that line. It will be better than you read line by line to the target line.
Example code for you: [In C++ is there a way to go to a specific line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)